# Google Script Running Extremely slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a google script attached to my google sheet. It's been working well so far apart from today when it's been extremely slow. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
var ssID = "1cpR6AVVpk9TF4_I38IFYPPOqk-_bSROHgVVYdaXLXOI";
var formID = "14foKaEoUA_lhDmJTJExwQ5vavsGJShWm_x1kaANLhwU";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("car_number");

var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
    var options = wsData.getRange(2,i + 1,wsData.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o) { return o[0]}).filter(function(o){return o !== ""});
    updateDropdownUsingTitle(label,options);
  });

}

function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  if (pos !== -1) {
  var item = items[pos];
  var ItemID = item.getId();
  updateDropdown(ItemID,values);
  }
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

Comment: You are calling `getValues` on every rows. Try to get only 1 time with `getDataRange().getValues()` and iterate through the data array. Read [Best Practices - Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Answer (score 2):

Try getting all values using batch operations, and use the minimum of API calls in the loop, like this:

```
function main() {
  // spreadsheet
  const ssID = '1cpR6AVVpk9TF4_I38IFYPPOqk-_bSROHgVVYdaXLXOI';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName('car_number');
  const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const labels = data.shift();
  const firstColumn = data.map(row => row[0]);
  // form
  const formID = '14foKaEoUA_lhDmJTJExwQ5vavsGJShWm_x1kaANLhwU';
  const form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  const items = form.getItems();
  const itemIds = items.map(item => item.getId());
  const itemTitles = items.map(item => item.getTitle());
  // action
  labels.forEach((label, rowIndex) => {
    const options = firstColumn.filter((option, optionIndex) => optionIndex >= rowIndex && option !== '');
    updateDropdownUsingTitle_(items, itemTitles, label, options);
  });
}

function updateDropdownUsingTitle_(items, itemTitles, title, values) {
  const pos = itemTitles.indexOf(title);
  if (pos !== -1) {
    updateDropdown_(items[pos], values);
  }
}

function updateDropdown_(item, values) {
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
}
```

With this pattern, the only API calls in the loop are in `item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values)`.